# r nested table with row percents

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, plyr, frequency-distribution

I am trying to create a nested table in R with Row Percents.

This is my dataset:

```
data("mtcars")
head(mtcars)
```

I am trying to create a summary table like this:

```
                vs = 0                             vs=1
         am =0         am-1                am =0        am-1
 Gear=3  12(100%)      0(0%)               3(100%)      0(0%)
 Gear=4  0(0%)         2(100%)             4(40%)       6(60%)
 Gear=5  0(0%)         4(100%)             0(0%)        1(100%)
```

I am not sure how. I tried this:

```
  ftable(mtcars$vs, mtcars$gear, mtcars$am, exclude= NULL)
```

But that just creates a summary of counts withn each subgroups and does not create `%` by rows. Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package `gtsummary` with its *stratified gtsummary tables* `tbl_strata` will give you what you want.

For further details on this see [here](https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/tbl_strata.html)

```
library(gtsummary)
  
mtcars |> select(gear, am, vs) |> 
  mutate(vs = paste0('vs = ', vs)) |> 
  tbl_strata(
    strata = vs,
    .tbl_fun = ~.x |> tbl_summary(by = am, missing = "no") |> 
      add_n()
  ) |> 
  modify_header(label ~"am")
```

[image]

---

**Addition**

Add `percent = "row"`:

```
mtcars |> select(gear, am, vs) |> 
  mutate(vs = paste0('vs = ', vs)) |> 
  tbl_strata(
    strata = vs,
    .tbl_fun = ~.x |> tbl_summary(by = am, percent = 'row', missing = "no") |> 
      add_n()
  ) |> 
  modify_header(label ~"am")
```

[image]

Comment: everything looks good except the %, the current solution is estimating the column%, I am interested in rowwise % , for example gear=4, vs=1, total = 10, to 40% and 60%.